# Did Morgoth know that cursing the Children of Húrin would help him?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, morgoth

If Túrin hadn't been a counselor in Nargothrond, it might not have fallen.  If he had not come among the people following Brandir, they might not have been found so quickly.  If he had not been cursed, Beleg probably wouldn't have died.

**Did Morgoth curse Túrin to do this damage on purpose?**

Comment: Morgoth was literally bending reality to go the way he wanted in general. I don't think there was much conscious intent or planning in specific events related to the curse on Hurin's family, but he would have known that it would work out for him.

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of the curse was to make Húrin suffer, by forcing him to watch all the evils that befell his children. Everything else was just a useful side effect.

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe, to some degree**. I don't think this is entirely answerable with the information we have. But we can set limits on the possibilities.

Morgoth, as a (fallen/former) Vala, could have had some knowledge of the future, at least in the early Ages of the World, since he experienced and participated in the Music of the Ainur.

On the other hand:

-he didn't pay much attention: "Little he knew yet [in the time of Feanor] concerning Men, for engrossed with his own thought in the Music he had paid small heed to the Third Theme of Iluvatar" - *Silmarillion* ch. 7, "Of the Silmarils and the Unrest of the Noldor"

-Men are not bound by the Music, having "a virtue to shape their life [...] beyond the Music of the Ainur, which is as fate to all things else"

So a clear and complete knowledge of Turin's future actions would not have been available to him, but he might have had some idea of the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Morgoth wanted Hurin and his family  to suffer.He was troubled by valour of men(especially of the House of Hador) who  aided the Eldar in the wars

Comment: Can you please provide sources for this?